# The math step in the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, fibonacci

Again new to Python.

> Write the Fibonacci sequence using a `for` loop.

I understand how `for` loops work, you're basically telling a function to run on repeat for a given range of numbers.

This might sound dumb but I can't wrap my head around the math step of it. I know Fibonacci is the two previous numbers added together give the current number in the I have seen a bunch of examples of the code but it's just not clicking for me. Here my code (I stole the math piece from someone else):

```
n = int(input("Please provide a sequence term: "))

def fib2(num):
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in range(num - 1):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return ("The nth term in the Fibonacci sequence is:", a)

print(fib2(n))
```

Also, can someone tell me how to make `nth` be the input value for `n`?

Comment: Did you tried to your code step by step and see what happen ?

Comment: Well `a, b = b, a + b` just updates a and b at the same time. the new value of `a` is `b` and the new value of `b` is `a+b`. Something like this is necessary since you need `b` to calculate the new `a` and `a` to calculate the new `b`. You cold use the following three lines instead: (1) b_copy = b, (2) b=a+b, (3) a=b_copy.

Comment: Which part is no clicking? Your code repeatedly adds the current and previous numbers together, producing a new pair for the next iteration.

Comment: Step through the code in your development environment, inspecting the variables step by step. And follow the logic on a piece of paper. This should clarify it.

Comment: `a, b = b, a + b` is mostly just shorthand for two assignment statements: `a = b` and `b = a + b` — which is the definition of the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) where each subsequent number is the sum of the previous two.

Comment: @martineau thank you, sounds dumb but I think I just needed to see it spelt out. It is making far more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @user2640045 thank you, sounds dumb but I think I just needed to see it spelt out. It is making far more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @martineau @RachelCyr be careful there. This would actually not give the fibonacci sequence since it would just double every step. You need to make `a` copy of a before you change it and then work with the copy like I suggested above.

Comment: @user2640045: Note how I said it's "mostly" is just like those two statements (ignoring that it happens simultaneously). It would, of course, actually require three statements to write out because of the need to first calculate and save the value of their sum before saving it at the new value of `b` (as @chepner's answer does).

Comment: @RachelCyr: You might want to consider trying an interactive debugger like [`ipdb`](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/). To install, run `pip install ipdb`, and then `import ipdb` at the top of your file. Then, you can set a point in execution where you want the program to stop using `ipdb.set_trace()` and subsequently step through each line of code at each iteration. IDEs like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) are also good for this sort of variable inspection. It will likely help you get a handle on things much faster than print statements (or SO questions :-) )

Comment: @marcman I went and down loaded this but I can't figure out how to execute it! any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first column are values for `i` - in every next iteration it increases.

```
i        1    1    2    3    5    8
         a    b  (a+b)  
0             a    b  (a+b)
1                  a    b  (a+b)
2                       a    b  (a+b)
3                            a    b
```

You may see, that in every next row (step, iteration) previous `b` becomes `a`, and previous `(a+b)` becomes `b`, so someone would have temptation write it in the form

```
 a = b 
 b = a + b
```

But it is wrong — the first statement changes `a`, whereas we need to use the *unchanged* value of it in the second statement.

We need to change values of *both* variables `a` and `b` on the basis of their *current, unchanged* values obtained from the preceding iteration.

In Python it is possible by using the single statement

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

---

*Note*

Instead of

```
return ("The nth term in the Fibonacci sequence is:", a)
```

use

```
return f"The {num}th term in the Fibonacci sequence is {a}"
```

to obtain a prettier output.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to expand the syntax a bit.

```
a = 1
b = 1
```

At this point, it's reasonable to assume that `a` is the first Fibonacci number, and `b` the second.

```
for i in range(num - 1):
   t = a + b
   a = b
   b = t
```

Note that `t` is the *next* Fibonacci number. The first time through the loop, we set `t` to be the *third* Fibonacci number, then *reset* `a` to be the second and `b` to be the third. The next time through the loop, `t` will be the fourth, `a` the third, and `b` the fourth.

Now, we can see that if you call `fib2(1)`, then `range(1-1) == range(0)` is *empty*, so the loop never enters, `a` remains unchanged, and so it returns the first Fibonacci number. `fib2(2)` uses `range(2-1) == range(1)`, so the loop executes once, etc.

One last thing: it looks like you probably want to either *print* a string

```
def fib2(num):
    ...
    print ("The nth term in the Fibonacci sequence is:", a)

fib2(5)
```

or return a string for to be printed by the caller

```
def fib2(num):
    ...
    return "The nth term in the Fiibonacci sequence is " + str(a)

print(fib2(num))
```

orb set, just *return* the Fibonacci number and let the caller decide what to do with it:

```
def fib2(num):
    ...
    return a

print("The 5th term in the Fibonacci sequence is", fib2(5))
```